# How to customize rte plugin in AEM for hyperlink

Tags: plugins, hyperlink, aem, customization, rte

As an author I want the default state of the hyperlink to be new tab so that I don’t have to change the target every time I create a new hyperlink. In the below picture instead of Target the default should be New Tab. Can anyone please help me how can I set the default target to New Tab instead of  Target(which is the dufault value currently)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try and implement your own RTE plugin

http://experience-aem.blogspot.com/2019/04/aem-65-touch-ui-rte-rich-text-editor-structured-content-plugin-creating-tooltips.html